# In the Amazon AWS API, how do you query if an item is Prime/Super Saver eligible?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I can't find anything in the API docs.  A few websites claim to filter Amazon for prime-only items, but I'm not sure how to tell if a given item is Prime/SuperSaver eligible or not.

Answer (score 3):

After some investigation, one viable-but-incomplete approach is iterating each of the sellers and checking to see if any one is Amazon.  That isn't complete (some 3rd party sellers also offer prime/ss) but it's a start.